# Passing metadata info to Stripe createToken call

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, stripe.js

I'm facing an issue while using Stripe.js in my javascript application. I successfully call `cart.createToken` like [explained here in the doc](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js#card-createToken), and I cannot find a way to give `metadata` info to Stripe.

Here is the data I'm passing:

```
  const data = {
    number: $form.find('[data-stripe=number]').val(),
    exp_month: $form.find('[data-stripe=exp_month]').val(),
    exp_year: $form.find('[data-stripe=exp_year]').val(),
    cvc: $form.find('[data-stripe=cvc]').val(),
    name: $form.find('[data-stripe=name]').val(),
    address_line1: $form.find('[data-stripe=address_line1]').val(),
    address_city: $form.find('[data-stripe=address_city]').val(),
    address_state: $form.find('[data-stripe=address_state]').val(),
    address_zip: $form.find('[data-stripe=address_zip]').val(),
    address_country: $form.find('[data-stripe=address_country]').val(),
    metadata: {
      vat_number: $form.find('[data-stripe=vat_number]').val()
    }
  };

  stripe.card.createToken(data, (status, response) => { ... })
```

I successfully see in my Chrome Network inspector that `vat_number` info is given to stripe

```
key=pk_test_foobar&payment_user_agent=stripe.js%2F81eca10&card[number]=4242+4242+4242+4242&card[exp_month]=12&card[exp_year]=19&card[cvc]=234&card[name]=GDG&card[address_line1]=20&card[address_city]=P&card[address_zip]=75004&card[address_country]=F&card[metadata][vat_number]=FR309483094830948
```

But unfortunately, in the Stripe answer, the `metadata` field is still an empty object `{}`. I quite need it in the response in my code, and how could I be sure that Stripe successfully has it.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Metadata](https://stripe.com/docs/api#metadata) can only be added to updatable objects. As [tokens](https://stripe.com/docs/api#token_object) are not updatable, you cannot provide metadata when creating a token.

Depending on what type of metadata you want to provide, you should pass the `metadata` parameter when [creating a charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) or a [customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer) with the card token.

Comment: Ok, did not know. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I'm seeing metadata work currently for the Stripe v2 JS SDK.  They may have changed their policy.